# Why does Android magnetic field sensor has a large component along gravity direction?

Tags: android, sensors, magnetometer

I have been collecting many hours of data using android magnetic field sensor. When collecting data, the phone's y axiz is held parallel to the gravity direction. For all the data samples the largest component of magnetic field sensor is along y axis.

When the magnetic field sensor is rotated using the rotation vector, again the largest component will be along gravity while the second largest component will be along y axis in world coordinates (North) as expected.

From my understanding, magnetic field sensor should point towards magnetic north, therefore the vector should be in a plane perpendicular to gravity. Is there a reason for the fact that it also has a large component along gravity?

(If it's a bug/ calibration error, I would appreciate suggestions on how that could be corrected)

Comment: Are you on the north pole or equator? Or south pole?

Comment: @greenapps my latitude is ~ 50 degrees (Canada). So above the tropic of Cancer.